# Encrypt existing column data in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to encrypt existing data in SQL database columns eg. 'FirstName', 'LastName'

I tried following query to encrypt a single row:

```
DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT FirstName FROM db_table WHERE Id = 518)
DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT LastName FROM db_table WHERE Id = 518)

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY DemoKey  DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCert; 

UPDATE db_table 
SET FirstName = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('DemoKey'), @FirstName),
    LastName = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('DemoKey'), @LastName)
WHERE Id = 518

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY DemoKey;
```

How do I encrypt multiple rows in the column?

Comment: Simply stop using the variables. Just update the table. But of course if you have already encrypted some rows you are you going to need to NOT encrypt them again or you will be encrypting the encrypted values.

Comment: If I remove the variables, the row data is not encrypted correctly.

In my case, There is another column in db_table named 'FullName'.
And from code behind, I am splitting the 'FullName' in to 'FirstName' and 'LastName' and then inserting into columns 'FirstName' and 'LastName'

'FullName' is already encrypted.

If I remove the variables from above update query, it is encrypting and storing FullName in both the columns 'FirstName' and 'LastName'

Comment: Well gosh, that was not clear at all from the original post since your sample query is selecting from two different columns. Just pull this into a cte or a temp table to split the values and then update. Or just do the split in your update statement.

Comment: What version of SQLServer are you using? If 2016 or above, have you checked dynamic data masking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2016 does it help?

Comment: @Sean Lange:

Removing the variable works fine for multiple rows. Without the need to create temp table.
It is encrypting the 'FirstName' and 'LastName' and displaying correctly in the front-end.

However, in database db_table, when I try to run select query on the 'FirstName' and 'LastName' columns to view decrypted values it is showing only single character.

For eg. If FirstName is 'Aaron', it is showing only 'A' in the column.
If LastName is 'Merino', it is showing only 'M' in the column.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove or modify where clause. That's all

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY DemoKey  DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCert; 

UPDATE db_table 
SET FirstName = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('DemoKey'), FirstName),
    LastName = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('DemoKey'), LastName)
```

Comment: Ummm.....this would update every single row to the same encrypted value. Need to removed the variables.

Comment: sorry check it now

Comment: This works..!
 However, in database db_table, when I try to run select query on the 'FirstName' and 'LastName' columns to view decrypted values it is showing only single character. For eg. If FirstName is 'Aaron', it is showing only 'A' in the column. If LastName is 'Merino', it is showing only 'M' in the column. Any idea why?